# Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_4: expected shape=(None, 156), found shape=(None, 256)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to test a Jupyter Notebook and an existing AI project (I'm just discovering the AI development concept).
There's a bug I cannot understand where the SBD and BDD matrix are created: according to the error message the matrix dimensions don't match.
Could you please help? Thank you :)

Here is the code:

```
def return_prediction(code):
   template = generate_template(code) # template generation --> ERROR
   #print(' '.join(template))
   predicted_var = generate_var(code) # variable generation --> OK
   #print(predicted_var)

   j=0
   #oov are replaced by variables:
   for i,word in enumerate (template):
       if word == '<oov>' and len(predicted_var) > j:
           template[i] = predicted_var[j]
           j=j+1    
   return ' '.join(template)

def generate_template(code):
   txt_trous = return_txt_trous_unique(code) # transformation from SBT to text with spaces"*
   encoded = encode_unique(txt_trous) # this text is encoded
   generated_template = return_generated_template(encoded) # generation of BDD template
   return generated_template

def return_generated_template(input_encoded):
   **print(input_encoded)**
   generated = generate_from_encoder_input(input_encoded)
   generated = generated.split(' ')
   return generated

def generate_from_encoder_input(encoder_input):
   encoder_input = encoder_input.reshape(1,-1)
   values,h,c = gen_encoder.predict(encoder_input)

   single_tok = np.zeros((1,1))
   single_tok[0,0] = word_to_ind_bdd['sostoken ']
   decoder_input = single_tok

   generated = []
   count = 0
   while(True):
       decoder_output,new_h,new_c = gen_decoder.predict([decoder_input]+[values,h,c])
       count +=1
       
       sampled_index = np.argmax(decoder_output[0,-1,:])
       sampled_word = ind_to_word_bdd[sampled_index]
       
       if sampled_word != ' eostoken' and sampled_index != 0:
           generated.append(sampled_word)
       if count >= max_words_bdd or sampled_word == ' eostoken':
           break
    
       h,c = new_h,new_c
       decoder_input[0,0] = sampled_index

   generated = ' '.join(generated)
   return generated
```

Here is the error obtained:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_4: expected shape=(None, 156), found shape=(None, 256)

And here is the stack trace (the 256 matrix below is displayed from code 'print(input_encoded)' in the function named 'return_generated_template'):

> [ 0  1  2  1  3  4  0  5  3  4  0  1  3  6  0  5  3  6  0  1  7 26  5  7
> 26  1  8  1  9 10  5  9 10  1  7 26  5  7 26  5  8  1  8  1  9 10  5  9
> 10  1  7 26  5  7 26  5  8  1  9 10  5  9 10  1 12  1 13  1 14  1 15  1
> 9 10  5  9 10  1  7 17  5  7 17  1 16 26  5 16 26  5 15  5 14  5 13  1
> 13  1 26  1 19  1  7 17  5  7 17  5 19  1 18  1 19  1  7 26  5  7 26  5
> 19  1 19  1  7 26  5  7 26  5 19  5 18  5 26  5 13  1 21  1 19  1  7 17
> 5  7 17  5 19  5 21  5 12  5  2 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27
> 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27
> 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27
> 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27
> 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27 27]
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20256/1349957589.py in 
> 1 for i in range(3):
> 2     a = randint(0,num_folder)
> ----> 3     print('\n\nPredicted BDD : \n',return_prediction(test[a]))
> 4     print('\nExpected BDD : \n', bdd[a],'\n\n')
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20256/2859014796.py in
> return_prediction(code)
> 1 def return_prediction(code):
> ----> 3     template = generate_template(code) # template generation
> 4     #print(' '.join(template))
> 5     predicted_var = generate_var(code) # variables generation
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20256/4105319748.py in
> generate_template(code)
> ----> 8     generated_template = return_generated_template(encoded) # template BDD generation
> 10     return generated_template
>
> ~\V2_template_attention.ipynb in
> return_generated_template(input_encoded)
> 442    "metadata": {},
> 443    "source": [
> --> 444     "Data encoding"
> 445    ]
> 446   },
>
> ~\V2_template_attention.ipynb in
> generate_from_encoder_input(encoder_input)
> 398    "cell_type": "markdown",
> 399    "metadata": {},
> --> 400    "source": [
> 402    ]
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py
> in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks,
> max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)    1749           for
> step in data_handler.steps():    1750
> callbacks.on_predict_batch_begin(step)
> -> 1751             tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)    1752             if
> data_handler.should_sync:    1753               context.async_wait()
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py
> in **call**(self, *args, **kwds)
> 883
> 884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
> --> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
> 886
> 887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py
> in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
> 931       # This is the first call of **call**, so we have to initialize.
> 932       initializers = []
> --> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
> 934     finally:
> 935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py
> in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
> 757     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
> 758     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
> --> 759         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(
> pylint: disable=protected-access
> 760             *args, **kwds))
> 761
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
> in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args,
> **kwargs)    3064       args, kwargs = None, None    3065     with self._lock:
> -> 3066       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)    3067     return graph_function    3068
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
> in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)    3461     3462
> self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
> -> 3463           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)    3464           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] =
> graph_function    3465
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py
> in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs,
> override_flat_arg_shapes)    3296     arg_names = base_arg_names +
> missing_arg_names    3297     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
> -> 3298         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(    3299             self._name,    3300             self._python_function,
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py
> in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature,
> func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies,
> arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value,
> override_flat_arg_shapes, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)    1005
> _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)    1006
> -> 1007       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)    1008     1009       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors,
> CompositeTensors,
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py
> in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
> 666         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
> 667         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
> --> 668           out = weak_wrapped_fn().**wrapped**(*args, **kwds)
> 669         return out
> 670
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py
> in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
> 992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
> 993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
> --> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
> 995             else:
> 996               raise

Comment: At one of your layers ` model_4`, the input that is sent is 256. But the during initialization, it was 128. Try checking the sizes in all intermediate layers.

Comment: What's the size of the image in the input layer?

Comment: Well, thank you for your answers, I'm afraid I cannot find how to check the size/initialization, as I'm really a beginner in this world... but thank you for this clue, I will search in this direction :)
Brgds